# glMultiDrawArrays buffering

Tags: c++, opengl

This might be again some stupid question and perhaps it's something really obvious what I am missing, but I having trouble to get glMultiDrawArrays working in OpenGL4.

I found plenty of explanations like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numarrays; i++)
    glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, arrayfirsts[i], arraycounts[i]);
```

is similar to that:

```
glMultiDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, arrayfirsts, arraycounts, numarrays);
```

And I am perfectly fine with that explanation. However, what I couldn't find out so far is- how has buffering to be done when I want to use glMultiDrawArrays?

Currently I have my code like this:

```
UINT vertssize = FloatsPerVertex * 4;
UINT texsize = TexCoords2D * 4;

VertsBuf[0] = RFX2*Z*(X - FX2);
VertsBuf[1] = RFY2*Z*(Y - FY2);
VertsBuf[2] = Z;
VertsBuf[3] = (U)*TexInfo[0].UMult;
VertsBuf[4] = (V)*TexInfo[0].VMult;

VertsBuf[5] = RFX2*Z*(X + XL - FX2);
VertsBuf[6] = RFY2*Z*(Y - FY2);
VertsBuf[7] = Z;
VertsBuf[8] = (U + UL)*TexInfo[0].UMult;
VertsBuf[9] = (V)*TexInfo[0].VMult;

VertsBuf[10] = RFX2*Z*(X + XL - FX2);
VertsBuf[11] = RFY2*Z*(Y + YL - FY2);
VertsBuf[12] = Z;
VertsBuf[13] = (U + UL)*TexInfo[0].UMult;
VertsBuf[14] = (V + VL)*TexInfo[0].VMult;

VertsBuf[15] = RFX2*Z*(X - FX2);
VertsBuf[16] = RFY2*Z*(Y + YL - FY2);
VertsBuf[17] = Z;
VertsBuf[18] = (U)*TexInfo[0].UMult;
VertsBuf[19] = (V + VL)*TexInfo[0].VMult;

DrawVerts(DrawVertsBuf, vertssize, texsize, Color);
```

with DrawVerts looking like that:

```
void DrawVerts(FLOAT* verts, UINT vertsize, UINT texsize, vec4f DrawColor)
{
    UINT TotalSize = vertsize + texsize;
    UINT stride = (sizeof(float) * FloatsPerVertex) + (sizeof(float) * TexCoords2D);
    UINT vertoffset = (sizeof(float) * FloatsPerVertex);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * TotalSize, verts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)vertoffset);

    glUniform4f(DrawTileDrawColor, DrawColor.X, DrawColor.Y, DrawColor.Z, DrawColor.W);

    // Draw
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertsize / FloatsPerVertex);

    // Clean up
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB);
}
```

How do I have to change that in order to call successfully glMultiDrawArrays? Of course I do have to add a counter then, that's obvious. I also tried some, but only ended up in crashing or no drawing so far. Tutorials and examples I found either spare the buffering part or they are for OpenGL1.x which I understand moving over to OpenGL4.
Currently its called up to 1000 times and I want to give it a try to optimize my code with it.

Comment: after some more google & friends I found that glBufferSubData may be suitable for that?

Comment: oh, please don't mind the glUniform4f, that's not important for the question itself.

Comment: Basically you need to write all your data into VB and draw it all with single `MultiDrawArrays`. Delay drawing until you've accumulated all fans you need to draw (`glMapBuffer`, `glBufferSubData`, or even single `glBufferData` from your client-side array will do), then issue drawing command. If that doesn't answer your question, you probably need to rephrase is so it will be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for answering :) - trying to clarify, my problem seems to be exactly that I don't know how to write correctly all the data into the VB and to accumulate all the fans, whatever I tried so far only resulted in a crash.

Comment: There are more than one way to do so. I suggest you post the code that gives you problems, as well as crash backtrace, if available.

Comment: an example of the one of these ways would be more than helpful. Somehow I don't know how to really start doing so, all the examples I found so far are only for old GL and of no help for me. If then still crashing I'm more than happy to post this code and the corresponding crash. It just seems I don't get the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example drawing two quads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

typedef struct {
    int elements_count;
    float *array;
} fan_s;


GLuint vbo_id;
#define VBO_SIZE 4096

static void setup_vbo(void) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_SIZE, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
}

static void draw_fans(const fan_s *fans, int num_fans) {
#define MAX_FANS 1024
    GLint fans_starts[MAX_FANS];
    GLsizei fans_sizes[MAX_FANS];

    float *mapping = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);

    int i;
    int num_elements_total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i != num_fans; ++i) {
        memcpy(mapping, fans[i].array, fans[i].elements_count * 3 * sizeof(float));
        mapping += fans[i].elements_count * 3;

        fans_starts[i] = num_elements_total;
        fans_sizes[i] = fans[i].elements_count;

        num_elements_total += fans[i].elements_count;
    }

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    glMultiDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, fans_starts, fans_sizes, num_fans);
}

static void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    float fan0_data[] = {
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 100.0, 0.0,
        100.0, 100.0, 0.0,
        100.0, 0.0, 0.0
    };
    float fan1_data[] = {
        200.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        200.0, 100.0, 0.0,
        300.0, 100.0, 0.0,
        300.0, 0.0, 0.0
    };
    fan_s fans[] = {
        4, fan0_data,
        4, fan1_data
    };
    draw_fans(fans, 2);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void reshape(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, w, h, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

static void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    if(key == 27) {
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("");

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glewInit();

    setup_vbo();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

For simplicity sake, I haven't checked any errors, including overflow (see `VBO_SIZE` and `MAX_FANS`).

Comment: this totally answers my question. Thank you! The existence and the usage of glMapBuffer is what I needed.

Comment: although, now I am wondering how it might work with glBufferData especially under consideration with usage of a stride :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `BufferData` replaces buffer with new one (some drives sometimes can avoid that if buffer is currently unused). You can update parts of buffer with `BufferSubData`, which should behave very much like `MapBuffer`, although calling it too many times per frame (e.g. once per triangle fan) is likely to reduce performance.

Comment: yes, I meant in combination with BufferSubData, to make some performance comparison. Although your note now pretty much answers that already. Also I think I know now how to do that. Thanks again.